# iOSバインドライブラリをXamarin.iOSプロジェクトで参照できない

Tags: ios, xamarin

以下のサイトを参考にネイティブのSDKをiOSバインドライブラリを介して
Xamarin.iOSプロジェクトで参照して使用したいと考えております。

[忍者AdMaxでバナー広告を表示する方法 -iOS編-](https://itblogdsi.blog.fc2.com/blog-entry-255.html)

iOSバインドライブラリプロジェクトにSDKのファイル「○○.a」や必要なクラス(ApiDefinitions.cs,StructsAndEnums.cs)などはサイトの通りに作成し、ビルドは成功するのですが、ビルドして生成されたdllをiOSプロジェクトに参照追加しても、
iOSバインドライブラリに定義されたinterfaceが参照できない状態です。
(名前空間も認識されていないようです。iOSバインドライブラリプロジェクトを参照するのではなくdllを直接参照しても同様でした。)

解決策やヒントになる情報をご教授いただければ幸いです。
よろしくお願いいたします。

開発環境
Windows 10
Visual Studio 2017 15.9.15
Xamarin.iOS and Xamarin.Mac SDK 12.4.0.64

Mac OS Mojave 10.14.6

Answer (score 0, accepted):

自己解決しました。
Visual StudioはWindowsではなく、Mac上でiOSバインドライブラリのプロジェクトをビルドする必要があるようです。
Mac上で作成したiOSバインドライブラリのDLLをWindowsPCへコピーして、
Windows上のVisual StudioのXamarin.iOSプロジェクトでそのDLLを参照設定に追加することで
名前空間が正しく認識されるようになりました。